Deboucing a BEMF in BLDC motor control
I came through some basic codes for sensorless control of BLDC motors and I find the following snippet of code that deals with debouncing BEMF signals come from comparators:
void Interrupt()
{
  // BEMF debounce
  int8_t j;
  for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    if(bldc_step & 1) {
      if(!C1OUT_bit)    j -= 1;
    }
    else {
      if(C1OUT_bit)     j -= 1;
    }
  }
  bldc_move();
  C1ON_bit = 1;      // clear the mismatch condition
  C1IF_bit = 0;      // Clear comparator 1 interrupt flag bit
}

The whole program can be found in
https://simple-circuit.com/bldc-brushless-motor-control-mikroc/
I have used to deal with switch debouncing codes, where a small delay is introduced between two successive checks to confirm the push or release of a switch, but here in this case, I realy don't understand how debouncing of a BEMF signal is done !!
I expect the variable bldc_step to vary between 1 and 6, since it represent the commutation steps  but yest it is ANDed (bitwise AND) with 1. The variable j is decremented insid the if-else statement.
Could anyone please explains to me,in detail, what is really happening inside the interrupt routine?

Are you talking about dry contact end-stop switches?  Then the easiest solution is a 0.1 uF cap across the switch.

If bldc_step does indeed vary from 1 to 6 (or actually 0 to 5, from reading the code), then bldc_step & 1 is only true for the odd values (think binary)... having determined this, the code then detects a low (!C1OUT_bit) or a high (C1OUT_bit), and adjusts the counter accordingly.
The odd vs even mechanism is related to the rising or falling BEMF for a given commutation step. The diagonal traces in the image below are the periods where that phase is undriven, and the BEMF appears... here, step 1 has falling voltage, step 2 has a rising voltage, etc... (NOTE: the steps shown here are numbered differently when compared to the firmware you're looking at)

source: Microchip AN2662
Paired with the enclosing loop, this means that the code will not progress until the signal has been stable for enough iterations - if the signal just changes to the desired state with no bounce, it'll run around the loop 10x times and complete... however if the signal is in the "wrong" state, it'll extend the time in that loop by one (i.e: j -= 1) for every iteration that the signal is "wrong".
I wouldn't call this "robust" code, as it could get stuck in the loop forever, if the interrupt fires and the signal never reaches the desired state. It would be better to also have a second counter that imposes a maximum loop count, and take action if a timeout occurs.
The expectation here is that the signal changes (firing the ISR), and may then bounce very briefly (the loop has no delays at all)... I don't know how fast the processor clock is, but 10x iterations likely won't take long, even for fairly tame core clocks...
Reading the code more completely, and referring to the schematic, we can see that they're using a comparator inside the PIC - C1IN+ is given the motor's "virtual ground", while C1IN0-, C1IN1- and C1IN2- are used for phases A, B and C respectively... the bldc_move() function then reassigns the comparator's negative input depending on the step (copied below, see CM1CON0).

source: Sensorless BLDC motor control with PIC ... (linked in question)
void bldc_move()        // BLDC motor commutation function
{
  switch(bldc_step){
    case 0:
      AH_BL();
      CM1CON0 = 0xA2;   // Sense BEMF C (pin RA3 positive, RB3 negative)
      break;
    case 1:
      AH_CL();
      CM1CON0 = 0xA1;   // Sense BEMF B (pin RA3 positive, RA1 negative)
      break;
    case 2:
      BH_CL();
      CM1CON0 = 0xA0;   // Sense BEMF A (pin RA3 positive, RA0 negative)
      break;
    case 3:
      BH_AL();
      CM1CON0 = 0xA2;   // Sense BEMF C (pin RA3 positive, RB3 negative)
      break;
    case 4:
      CH_AL();
      CM1CON0 = 0xA1;   // Sense BEMF B (pin RA3 positive, RA1 negative)
      break;
    case 5:
      CH_BL();
      CM1CON0 = 0xA0;   // Sense BEMF A (pin RA3 positive, RA0 negative)
      break;
  }
  bldc_step++;
  if(bldc_step >= 6)
    bldc_step = 0;
}


Whenever an interrupt is generated by the comparator, C1OUT_bit can be high or low, and inside the for loop, both cases are chacked and j is decremented in both. it seems the program will stack inside the for loop forever. I expect the debouce algorithm to avoid the uncertainties of the comparator at transition time (from high to low or low to high). In this code what will make the PIC go out of the for loop since C1OUT_bit is checked for both Hign and Low states and J is decremeted ?

"inside the for loop, both cases are chacked" ... only one of these cases is checked, but which depends on the commutation step!

For motor debounce from deadzone flyback or Back EMF , in the provided code, debouncing ensures stable detection of back electromotive force (BEMF) signals, critical for determining rotor position. The debouncing routine uses a loop to repeatedly check the comparator output (C1OUT_bit) for consistency. Any bounce (momentary fluctuation) is filtered out by reducing the loop counter (j) when inconsistent readings occur. This ensures the motor commutation logic operates reliably.
This method effectively implements a software debounce mechanism by requiring a series of consistent states before proceeding.
Although, generally an RC snubber is used to limit the voltage Idc*R to some safe limit to whatever the sense input allows or the Vds of the driver permits.  The time constant RC= Tau <= deadtime T in the hardware. [x us] where x can be more or less than 1 us and Idc = V+/DCR and DCR is the DC resistance of the coil.
